# Post request with --data-raw in Cypress JS

Tags: javascript, post, http-post, cypress

Good day!

I have a problem with my autotest on JS cypress.
I need to send post request in autotest. Here it is as I send it by hands:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://test.com/service' \
--header 'Token: n7n7n7n7n7' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'text: v3'
```

This is how I try to send post in js test:

```
cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http//:test.com/service',
            headers: {
                'Token': n7n7n7n7n7,
                'Content-Type':'text/plain'
            },
            data: "text: v3"
        }).then((res)=>{
            expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
        })
```

It doesnt work, instead of 200 I get 400, in cypress log I see:

The request we sent was:

Method: POST
URL: http//:test.com/service
Headers: {
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"X-Gitlab-Token": "n7n7n7n7n7",
"Content-Type": "text/plain",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
"accept": "/",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"content-length": 0
}

And no data.

How can I send data-raw in cypress request?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check that your url is correct? Currently seeing it as `http:`, but I'd expect `http://`?

Comment: sorry, ive changed this url to make post here and it is just a typo here

Comment: Is there any information in the 400 response as to what is happening?

Comment: I ve found the way:
so if you need to send data raw - request exaple here:
```
cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http//:test.com/service',
            headers: {
                'Token': n7n7n7n7n7,
                'Content-Type':'text/plain'
            },
            body: "text: v3"
        }).then((res)=>{
            expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with the script:
cy.request({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http//:test.com/service',
headers: {
'authhorization': "n7n7n7n7n7",
'Content-Type':'text/plain'
},
body: {"text": "v3"}
}).then((res)=>{
expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).